Mysql and mybatis insert into select from using foreach
I have a list of elements [a, b, c, d].
I also have a table called ticket that looks like this:
order_pnr_id             bigint unsigned  default '0'    not null,
order_id                 bigint unsigned  default '0'    not null,
reference_ticket_id      bigint unsigned  default '0'    not null,

I am going to insert data into a new table but I want to fetch the data from the ticket table and insert it directly. However, I also want to insert the list of elements [a, b, c, d] by iterating through the list.
I know I can use INSERT INTO SELECT FROM... clause, but how can I iterate through the list at the same time? Can I use foreach with the clause?
Ideally, I want this to work:
INSERT INTO new_table
(
    order_pnr_id,
    order_id,
    reference_ticket_id,
    new_element

)
<foreach item="elem" collection="elements" open="(" separator="," close=")">
SELECT
    order_pnr_id,
    order_id,
    reference_ticket_id
    #{elem}
FROM
    ticket
WHERE
    order_id = 1

</foreach>


so this inserts four rows

Convert your list of elements [a, b, c, d] to JSON array '["a", "b", "c", "d"]'. Then use single
INSERT INTO new_table (
    order_pnr_id,
    order_id,
    reference_ticket_id,
    new_element
    )
SELECT ticket.order_pnr_id,
       ticket.order_id,
       ticket.reference_ticket_id,
       elements.new_element 
FROM ticket
-- CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(#{json_elem_array},
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE('["a", "b", "c", "d"]',  
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (new_element CHAR(1) PATH '$')) elements
WHERE ticket.order_id = 1

Adjust new_element CHAR(1) to proper datatype.

If you are using MySQL version 8.0, you can use WITH clause.
INSERT INTO new_table
(
  order_pnr_id,
  order_id,
  reference_ticket_id,
  new_element
)
WITH temp_table AS (
<foreach item="elem" collection="elements" separator=" union ">
  SELECT #{elem} elem
</foreach>
)
SELECT
  order_pnr_id,
  order_id,
  reference_ticket_id
  temp_table.elem
FROM ticket
CROSS JOIN temp_table
WHERE order_id = 1

